# What are awesome things that D&D had historically that are (or were) missing in 5e?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, history-of-gaming

For example, I had NO IDEA that in earlier editions of the game, there were rules for spending gold on strongholds and keeps and other cool structures. Makes all that gold characters accumulate much more useful. Matt Colville's recent products seek to address the absence of this.

Morale as a mechanic (I believe this is well represented in the OSR, and an optional rule in the 5e DMG)

Minions in 4e. Hirelings (recently incorporated into 5e).

XP being tethered to Gold.

Please note that I'm not saying that all of these things NEED to be in D&D 5e. It's just cool to consider mechanics that used to exist in the game that are forgotten by the wider community. There's such a rich trove of stuff in the history of this game.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, a list of "things in other D&D editions that *aren't* in 5e" is a very wide list; as such, this question is likely too broad to be meaningfully answerable. Relevant metas: [Are list/collection questions on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/176/33569), [What are list questions?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6442/33569) This question seems more like a discussion prompt that may be better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/33569).

Answer (score -1):

## Magic Item / Spell Creation Tables

AD&D (2e) has some very exact tables/processes for crafting your own magic items and spells.

For instance, if you wanted to make an item that combined *Boots of Elvenkind* and *Slippers of Spider Climbing*, you just looked it up on a table and you knew about how much down time it'd take and what it'd cost.

Want to make a +1 Dagger as a gift for a visiting noble? There was a table for making that. Need some super niche spell to do something cool? There was a table for that too.

5e has none of that. Granted, there are a *few* instances of "Cast spell X for 30 days and it becomes permanent until dispelled", but by and large, when it comes to end game "What cool stuff can I do now", you're just shooting in the dark and making guesses.

Comment: What's the rationale behind the down votes?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but the downvotes are likely because this answer doesn't even begin to fully answer the question. We expect answers to be complete answers to the question so that in the end we have one, best answer that fully solves the issue. I'm sure you realized that such an all-inclusive list would be nearly impossible, and I'd agree. That's probably why the question was closed.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose: That makes more sense when you put it in that context. Thanks for the heads up!